# How to update an IndexedDB ObjectStore Name?

Tags: indexeddb

One way to do it is to create a new objectStore with the new name and copy the data of the original over, but is there a way to modify the name of the existing objectStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took another look at the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#object-store), and it does not look like there is a way to modify the name of an existing object store. Your idea of creating a new store, copying over the objects, and deleting the old store, is probably the only and best way.

Comment: Josh is right. There's a chrome bug open for this feature. http://crbug.com/457447